# restricting domain of dominant map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume that there is a dominant map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between two variety(I'm considering affine variety over $\mathbb{C}$ in particular).

Then, by [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_algebraic_varieties#Fibers_of_a_morphism), we know that there is an open subset $U\subseteq Y$ such that for any irreducible closed set $W\subseteq Y$ intersecting $U$, there is a component $Z\subseteq f^{-1}(W)$
 of dimension $= \dim W + \dim X-\dim Y$.

What I want is finding a irreducible closed set $Z'$ of dimension exactly $\dim W$(thus $Z'$ is not an irreducible component of the preimage of $W$ in general)
such that the restriction $\bar{f}:Z'\rightarrow W$ is still dominant.

ex) $f:\mathbb{C}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2, (x,y,z)\mapsto (y,z), W=\mathbb{C}^2$, then $Z'=\left\{c\right\}\times \mathbb{C}^2$ for any $c\in \mathbb{C}$ obviously works.(while too trivial in this case)

I hope this would be always possible in this setting, but if strange obstruction exists, then I want to find such under the following stronger condition: $W$: curve(i.e, dimension 1), or $f$: surjective(not merely dominant)

Or any possible affirmative assertion with strengthened assumption would be welcome, and thank your for your answer in advance.

Comment: If $X$ is an affine open set of an irreducible $Y$, the inclusion is dominant, but the inverse image of any point in $Y-X$ is empty. So, you have to modify your question.

Comment: Dear @Mohan I have edited the line. It's the theorem (b) on the linked page